# Merging videos with different starting times not working with ffmpeg and -itsoffset

Tags: ffmpeg

I developed a video conferencing app that records the videos separately, and I am now looking for a way to merge them. At the moment I am experimenting with -itsoffset and hstack to stack 2 videos side by side using this command:

```
ffmpeg \
-itsoffset 17 -i smaller.mp4 \
-itsoffset 0 -i bigger.mp4 \
-filter_complex hstack=inputs=2 \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 out.mp4
```

The result is a side by side video where both streams remain frozen for 17 seconds then start playing, even the bigger.mp4 video that should start at time 0.

Any help would be really appreciated!

ffmpeg verbose:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10+deb8u1)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enab                                                                                                                                       le-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-nonfree --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'smaller.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 444 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 330 kb/s, 32 fps, 32 tbr, 16384 tbn, 64 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 103 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'bigger.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
  Duration: 00:00:22.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 290 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 177 kb/s, 32 fps, 32 tbr, 16384 tbn, 64 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 103 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> hstack:input0 (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> hstack:input1 (graph 0)
  hstack (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] 264 - core 146 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex                                                                                                                                        subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_thre                                                                                                                                       ads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scene                                                                                                                                       cut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 8:3], q=-1--1, 32 fps, 16384 tbn, 32 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
frame=  709 fps=130 q=-1.0 Lsize=     573kB time=00:00:22.12 bitrate= 212.2kbits/s dup=544 drop=0 speed=4.05x
video:478kB audio:81kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.445685%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] frame I:3     Avg QP:16.86  size: 38355
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] frame P:190   Avg QP:18.22  size:  1633
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] frame B:516   Avg QP:16.23  size:   123
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] consecutive B-frames:  1.3%  2.8%  6.8% 89.1%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] mb I  I16..4:  6.6% 54.8% 38.6%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] mb P  I16..4:  0.4%  1.5%  0.2%  P16..4:  8.7%  4.0%  1.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:83.3%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8:  4.2%  0.3%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:95.4%  L0:37.2% L1:58.9% BI: 4.0%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] 8x8 transform intra:66.2% inter:63.4%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 66.1% 65.6% 21.6% inter: 1.7% 1.1% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 21% 26% 11% 42%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 23% 13%  5%  7%  8%  7%  7%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 24%  9%  6%  7%  7%  6%  7%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 46% 25% 20%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:1.1% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] ref P L0: 66.0% 19.4% 12.0%  2.6%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] ref B L0: 87.2% 11.8%  1.0%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] ref B L1: 95.2%  4.8%
[libx264 @ 0x206ed00] kb/s:176.52
[aac @ 0x204aa00] Qavg: 247.398
```